# Filling empty values in one dataframe based on column in another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a first dataframe, which includes some missing values in a column. I then have a second dataframe, which includes a more complete dataset, but not necessarily at the same exact indices. As an example, here's a depiction of the situation:

[image]

It's clear that filling for the indices that match is easy (e.g., the first nan can be filled with 634 from the second dataframe). For the indices that aren't in the other DF, I would like to interpolate between the two nearest values (e.g., to fill the 5.0, I would like to interpolate between 4.8 and 5.2 in df2). I'm not sure how to do this, at least not in a pandas way. My instinct is to iterate through the missing values, manually find the closest index in df2 and then interpolate between. I'm sure there's a smarter way of going about this though. Any tips?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Applying interpolation on DataFrame based on another DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51838355/applying-interpolation-on-dataframe-based-on-another-dataframe)

you can basically combine both dataframes, remove duplicates while keeping the first (based on index), and then sort by index and interpolate

Comment: Yes, I think this helps, but the difference is that I don't want any of the extra values (e.g., I don't want 5.2, 5.6, 6.0, etc. to be in my final df, I only want the indices that are in df1 to exist). Which is why i was avoiding combining the dataframes, because then I'm not sure how to remove the rows that are in df2 that aren't in df1.

Comment: oh, you can remove that by doing a left merge on he first df like `final_df = df1[['index']].merge(combined_df[['index','value']], how='left') `

Answer (score 1):

I changed column name `Index`->`arg` to avoid confusion.

First load data frames

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'arg': {0: 1.0, 1: 2.3, 2: 2.5, 3: 3.6, 4: 5.0, 5: 5.9, 6: 6.0, 7: 6.2, 8: 6.3, 9: 6.4},
    'value': {0: 634.0, 1: 500.0, 2: 439.0, 3: 287.0, 4: 641.0, 5: 212.0, 6: 374.0, 7: 358.0, 8: 600.0, 9: 755.0}
}) 
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'arg': {0: 1.0, 1: 1.4, 2: 1.8, 3: 2.2, 4: 2.4, 5: 2.8, 6: 3.2, 7: 3.6, 8: 4.0, 9: 4.4, 10: 4.8, 11: 5.2, 12: 5.6, 13: 6.0, 14: 6.4},
    'value': {0: 634, 1: 8, 2: 218, 3: 813, 4: 338, 5: 339, 6: 935, 7: 287, 8: 376, 9: 481, 10: 727, 11: 555, 12: 50, 13: 374, 14: 755}
})
```

Calculate left join on df1 and update values from df1 to df2.

```
temp = df1.merge(df2, on="arg", how="left")
df1["value"] = temp.value_y.combine_first(temp.value_x)
```

get still NaN values

```
to_interpolate = df1[df1.value.isna()]
```

add arguments without values to df2 and interpolate their values.

```
df3 = pd.concat([to_interpolate, df2]).sort_values("arg")
df3.value.interpolate(inplace=True)
```

repeat merging.

```
temp = df1.merge(df3, on="arg", how="left")
df1["value"] = temp.value_x.combine_first(temp.value_y)
print(df1)
```

Outputs:

```
   arg  value
0  1.0  634.0
1  2.3  500.0
2  2.5  439.0
3  3.6  287.0
4  5.0  641.0
5  5.9  212.0
6  6.0  374.0
7  6.2  358.0
8  6.3  600.0
9  6.4  755.0
```